# Vitepress empty page layout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitepress

I want to create a landing page for a documentation and I dont any layout option. How can I create a landing that points to a Vue component directly?

```
---
layout: none
---

<Landing />
 
<script setup>
import Landing from "./components/Landing.vue"

</script>
```

I want one page to be empty. Just my component.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there is no way to implement a page without layout `page`, `home` or `doc` in vitepress. [More info](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/issues/1091).